# Proper way to show array inside an array with v-for

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-for

I am trying to display the values of the text array/object but I am getting an output trying to show me paragraphs for every name inside the array/object.

Link to current result: [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfohH.jpg)

I am fairly new to vue.js so any tips are welcome!

```html
<template>
  <div class="education center">
    <div v-if="object.timelines != null">
      <template v-for="(time,index) in object.timelines">
        <p :key="index">{{ time.schoolyear }}</p>
        <div :key="index" v-bind="time" v-for="(text,index) in time.text">
          <p :key="text">Degree: {{ text.degree }}</p>
          <p>Institution: {{ text.institution }}</p>
          <p>Where: {{text.where}}</p>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  el: ".education",
  data: function() {
    return {
      object: {
        timelines: [
          {
            schoolyear: "2016 - 2017",
            text: [
              { degree: "Applied Computer Science" },
              { institution: "Thomas More University of Applied Science" },
              { where: "Belgium, Geel" }
            ]
          },
          {
            schoolyear: "2018 - 2019",
            text: [
              { degree: "Business IT" },
              { institution: "HAMK University of Applied Science" },
              { where: "Finland, Hämeenlinna" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I only want to show text.degree once for schoolyear="2016 - 2017"

Comment: try  `<p :key="text" v-if="time.schoolyear=='2016 - 2017'">Degree: {{ text.degree }}</p>`

Comment: That does unfortunately not fix the issue. Also seems like a huge amount of work if you are working with large arrays...

Comment: please rephrase your issue since i misunderstood you

Comment: Do you have control over the object/timeline?

Comment: i see that your text object should be like i did [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2zo976qn5)

Comment: or you could try [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/3qpk48o7zm)

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you want, but maybe is it that you want to iterate through the `.text` array and, for each entry in the array, display both its key and its content. If so, you might try something like:

```
<p v-for="(entry, index) in time.text" :key="index">
    {{Object.keys(entry)[0]}}: {{Object.values(entry)[0]}}
</p>
```

If you need to worry about title case for the keys, you could either use a computed property to convert the array, or define a method to convert each string.

Comment: You could use a filter to uppercase the first letter of the keys

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to [Boussadjra Brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim) for providing the codepen wich resolved my issue.

I will first rephrase the question and then copy the solution.

**The question**: I want to print out values from an array inside a javascript object. In my `<div>`tag is is currently printing trying to print out `text.institution` for each element in the `text` array.

resulting in vue.js trying to show `<p>Institution: {{ text.institution }}</p>` 
for **degree**, **institution** and **where**. Giving a browser output of:

`<p>Degree:</p>`

`<p>Institution: Thomas More University of Applied Science"</p>`

`<p>Where:</p>`

for `text.where` this would change to

`<p>Degree:</p>`

`<p>Institution:</p>`

`<p>Where: Belgium, Geel</p>`

**The answer**: Yet again a huge thanks to [Boussadjra Brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim) for showing the solution.

```html
/* eslint-disable vue/require-v-for-key */
<template>
  <div class="education center">
    <div v-if="object.timelines != null">
      <template v-for="(time,index) in object.timelines">
        <p :key="index">{{ time.schoolyear }}</p>
        <div :key="index" :set="text = time.text">
          <p>Degree: {{ text.degree }}</p>
          <p>Institution: {{ text.institution }}</p>
          <p>Where: {{text.where}}</p>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  el: ".education",
  data(){
    return {
      object: {
        timelines: [
          {
            schoolyear: "2016 - 2017",
            text: {
              degree: "Applied Computer Science",
              institution: "Thomas More University of Applied Science",
              where: "Belgium, Geel"
            }
          },
          {
            schoolyear: "2018 - 2019",
            text: {
              degree: "Business IT",
              institution: "HAMK University of Applied Science",
              where: "Finland, Hämeenlinna"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I changed the text array from square brackets to curly brackets and instead of using a `v-for=` I changed to a `:set=`.